# Are webviews accessible?

Tags: android, accessibility

Are WebViews in android accessible? I mean can a screenreader read the contents in a webview.
I have read somewhere that the default android browser is not accessible. But does that mean the same for webview as well?

Answer (score 1):

Webviews are only accessible in Android 4.0 and above.

Comment: any clues/link which might help me in achieving the same on 2.3.4?